# Is it possible to do live text-replace in shell?

Tags: zsh, line-editor

I run `zsh` on my machine. I was wondering if I can do text-replace in shell. For example `fn[SPACE/TAB]`should be replaced with `function`. On `OSX` there is the option of keyboard-shortcuts but they don't run on `chrome` or `shell`. Is there a way to tweak the OS so that it interprets `fn` as `function`?

It'd be amazing if this could be achieved.

Answer (score 3):

`zsh` provides plenty of rope a portion of which is the `_user_expand` feature to provide so-called "user expansions" of random inputs to random outputs. For example.

```
# turn on completion system
autoload -U compinit
compinit
# how to mangle inputs; this is a hash or "associative array" of terms
declare -A manglements
manglements=( fn function )
# register mangler and enable _user_expand
zstyle ':completion:*:user-expand:*' user-expand '$manglements'
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _user_expand _complete _ignored
```

With this set in `.zshrc` or the like, typing `fn`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> should replace that text with `function` (or at least it does for me inputting the above lines into zsh 5.3.1 run as `zsh -f` to avoid conflicting with any extant configuration). To reduce the input to just `fn`<kbd>tab</kbd> set the `add-space` setting

```
zstyle ':completion:*:user-expand:*' add-space 1
```

though if you really want a magical <kbd>space</kbd> instead of <kbd>tab</kbd> completion, this requires that the space bar have a widget bound to it, which is a slightly more significant (and dangerous) change.

```
declare -A manglements
manglements=( fn function )

function magic-space-bar {
   local -a le_vlapoi

   # split on words, see zshexpn(1)
   le_vlapoi=(${(z)BUFFER})

   # only mangle the first word, not surprisingly in middle of some
   # "echo blah fn ..." sequence (this is the same as the `alias -g`
   # rake problem waiting to whap you in the face)
   if [[ $#le_vlapoi -eq 1 ]]; then
      local romoi
      romoi=$manglements[$le_vlapoi[-1]]
      if [[ -n $romoi ]]; then
         le_vlapoi[-1]=$romoi
         BUFFER="$le_vlapoi"
      fi
   fi

   # ensure the typed space happens regardless
   BUFFER="$BUFFER ";
   CURSOR=$#BUFFER
}

zle -N magic-space-bar
autoload -U compinit
compinit
bindkey ' ' magic-space-bar
bindkey -M isearch ' ' self-insert
```

Comment: ```fn``` ```TAB``` gives two options to choose from namely ```fn``` and ```function```. Although it aproximately solves the problem, not completely. I've to ```TAB``` through the selection different from just typing ```fn``` and then proceeding to type and on next char to have already replaced it with function. This additionally wouldn't work say if you run ```ocaml``` interpreter. I was thinking of a way to trick the OS into thinking that when ```fn``` is inserted that ```function``` instead was inserted. Ideally one would have text-replace as one types in all programs.